# changing API LEVEL IN ANDROID

Tags: android-studio

How can I change my application's API level after selecting it previously when I am making a new project?
[after selecting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNwFh.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways of changing i'll tell you:

Go to menu select "File" then select "Project Structure"
or just give "ctrl + alt + shift + s".

The android Studio will show the configuration of the project.

Select "Modules" in the menu then select "App" and in the menu on top right select "Default config", there you will see the min and target api.

---

The second way is:

Just go to the end of the tree project where is the packages, in the end there is the "Gradle Scripts" open him and select the second "build.gradle(Module)" open this file. you will find the min API and target API, just change it.

After changing go to "File" and select "Sync Project with Gradle Files".

Answer (score 0):

The minApi version is set in your `build.gradle` file.
You should be able to navigate to your `build.gradle` file and find within it a section that looks similar to the below code:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.streem.android.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And you can update the minSdkVersion to be whatever value you would like to update it to.